# wierd matrix behavior in C

Tags: c, matrix, allocation

My C program uses 2 int matrix. The first matrix is n x n and allocated this way:

```
void alocar_matriz(int ***matriz)
{
    int i;
    if((*matriz = (int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\a\t\tERRO: NAO FOI POSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(((*matriz)[i] = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\a\t\tERRO: NAO FOI POSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA!!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The second is a triangle inferior matrix, allocated this way:

```
void alocar_matriz_mao_dupla(int ***matriz)
{
    int i;
    if((*matriz = (int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\a\t\tERRO: NAO FOI POSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(((*matriz)[i] = (int*)calloc(i+1,sizeof(int)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\a\t\tERRO: NAO FOI POSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA!!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Having the first matrix data, I have a function that modify the second (triangle) matrix values (where "mat" is the first nxn matrix and "mao_dupla" is the second triangle matrix):

```
void verifica_mao_dupla(int **mat, int **mao_dupla)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            { 
                if(mat[i][j]==1 && mat[j][i]==1)
                    mao_dupla[j][i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is: the function void verifica_mao_dupla(int **mat, int **mao_dupla), which should only modify elements of the triangle matrix "mao_dupla", is also modifying the matrix "mat" elements. This is not supposed to happen. I don't know what is the error. Help please

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through the code one line at a time. Examine `mat` after every line. That will help you narrow down where the problem is. Much better to learn to debug yourself than ask others to do it for you. And you need to provide an [mcve] if you really need someone else to help with the debugging.

Comment: Best to avoid 3-star programming anyway.

Comment: Given that you haven't posted all of the code, it's hard to be sure what's going on.  But in your `verifica_mao_dupla` function, let's say `i` is `2` and `j` is `0`.  If the `mat[i][j]` and `mat[j][i]` conditions are met, you're going to write outside the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you modify `mao_dupla[j][i]`, `j` is less than `i`.  In that case the write exceeds the bounds of `mao_dupla[j]`, producing undefined behavior.  Moreover, you're performing more work than you need to do.

You should be able to solve the problem simply by improving your handling of the array indices and changing the loop limits:

```
void verifica_mao_dupla(int **mat, int **mao_dupla) {
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {      // no need for an i == 0 iteration
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {  // fixed loop bounds
            // note: j cannot be equal to i here
            if(mat[i][j]==1 && mat[j][i]==1) {
                mao_dupla[i][j] = 1;  // swapped index order
            }
        }
    }
}
```